# Why Set doesn't provide a getter?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, ecmascript-6, set

Unlike a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), which has methods to set and get values, why does a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) only allows to add an element, but not retrieve it?

```
// Map
let cache = new Map();
cache.set('name', 'map');
let val = cache.get('name');

// Set
let mySet = new Set();
set.add( {'name': 'hello'} );
set.add( {'name': 'world'} );
```

**How to get the second object from mySet?**

Comment: A Map has a key and a value, and you can retrieve the value by knowing the key. A Set has a value only, and the only way to retrieve the value would be using the value you've already got. What you do need is `has` to see if the Set contains the value.

Comment: That explains it. If you post it as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Map has a key and a value, and you can retrieve the value by knowing the key.

A Set has just vales, and the only way to retrieve a value would be using the value you've already got.

What you do need is a the `has` method to check if the Set contains a value.